# Where do I define custom global variables in my Joomla project?

Tags: custom-component, custom-module, global-configuration, variable

I'm using Joomla 3.9.18 and I've got a project including a component and a couple of modules. I've got a couple of variables that are the same throughout the whole project (like some prefixes and a path to an image server), but now when I need to change them, I need to change them everywhere. I want to define these variables in one spot so I only need to change them there.

Where do I define variables like these and how can I access them in my component and modules?

I know configuration.php isn't an option because of core-hacks. I've read something about component options, but I'm still fairly new so I don't really understand how it works. Is this the way to go? And if yes, how does it work (easily explained)?

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [Adding Configuration Parameters](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_configuration/en).

This then makes your configuration parameters available via the params, these can be obtained anywhere using the JComponentHelper class or via your own method. Example:

`JComponentHelper::getParams('com_your_component')->get('yourcustomfield', 'a-fallback-value');`

As an alternative, you can create a `defines.php` at your site root, and include global constants there, as per [index.php](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/26aa33ca775f206451f3f701ae11f36c4c246550/index.php#L29)

Comment: I don't think it's mentioned in the tutorial step, but if in your component's Table class you set the protected variable $_jsonEncode to include your params field (eg $_jsonEncode = array('params');) then Joomla will do the conversion in/out of the json-encoded format which is used to store params, rather than you needing to override the Table bind() function. See libraries/src/Table/Table.php and the example in administrator/components/com_contact/tables/contact.php.